# Add a pkcs12 client certificate to a phonegap app

Tags: cordova, ssl, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, pkcs#12

I have a .pfx cert (pkcs12) which I need to bundle into my app to connect over SSL.

When I run the app I get the following error:

The server “xyz” requires a client certificate.

I have had no experience with this but from researching around I can find no way of achieving this through PhoneGap.

I want to run this in IOS and Android.

Has anyone done this before? Any ideas on a solution?